# Principle of Catalysts

Tags: reaction-mechanism

How exactly do Catalysts work? In the cracking of Alkanes, Aluminum Oxide is used as a catalyst. However how does Aluminum Oxide decrease the conditions required to undergo cracking. At the molecular level, what is actually happening? How can a catalyst increase the rate of a reaction without being used itself?

Comment: Who says catalysts are not used? They are, but they are being regenerated. E.g  A + B -> P may be catalyzed, e.g. as A + C -> AC,   AC + B -> P + C.  Many redox reactions are catalyzed by ions of transition metals with variable oxidation state, like Fe or Mn.. The point of catalysis is that the reaction path involving a catalyst have lower activation energy(ies). Like going on a bicycle either across high hill versus 2 or more small ones.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how a metallic surface catalyzes the reaction of $\ce{H2}$ + $\ce{O2}$. First $\ce{H2}$ reacts with the metal $\ce{M}$, making weak $\ce{M-H}$ bonds at its surface. As a consequence, the covalent bond between the two $\ce{H}$ atoms is extended, and weakened. Seen from outside, it looks as if the surface of the metal $\ce{M}$ is covered by nearly free $\ce{H}$ atoms. If $\ce{O2}$ molecules are touching one of these $\ce{H}$ atoms, it can make a O-H hydrogen bond in  O-O-H-M. If this hydrogen bond is weaker than the $\ce{H-M}$, the reactive molecule $\ce{HO2}$ will quit the metallic surface and reacts later with other atoms, molecules or radical to produce $\ce{H2O}$ at the end.

The catalytic effect of $\ce{Al2O3}$ on alkanes may be similar to this mechanism.